# Click on anchor tag is not working in chrome

Tags: php, html, drupal-6

Iam developing on a website using drupal 6.26. In my home page i displayed thumbnail image within anchor tag. On click on the same, it will navigate to some other page of the site. Iam applying href to anchor tag and image path to thumbnail from database. I wrote whole functionality in a block and i called that block in page-front.tpl.php. This is working fine. But this anchor tag is not clickable in Chrome.
Some times its clickable. But most of the times its not clickable. Can anybody tell me, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you look at the output HTML code and maybe post it here?

Comment: A fiddle or some code snippets will help others help you.